# Is memory sequentially allocated when using new in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

Lets say that we allocate memory for 5 variables of type `int` using the following:
`int* ptr = new int[5];`
Then if I am right the addresses of the allocated memory should be random? For example:
If the address of `&ptr[0]` is let's say is 0x7fffa07f7560 then the address for `&ptr[1]` should be random instead of being 0x7fffa07f7564.

Only when we allocate the memory in the stack using `int array[5];` should we get sequential addresses which are 4 bytes apart.

Comment: When we allocate memory, we obtain a contigous area. So we are sure that all data of an array are at successive addresses.

Comment: Arrays are always continuous, that is what *array* means.

Comment: `ptr[x]` is `*(ptr + x)`. It wouldn't work if arrays weren't allocated contiguously. One of the only thing you can predict about the result of `new` is that the obtained storage is contiguous.

Comment: Two calls to `new` may not place the memory blocks in contiguous areas.  Some OSes have different areas depending on the allocation size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory addresses of unrelated memory blocs are unspecified and should be seen as an implementation detail. But `int *ptr = new int[5]` allocates a single bloc containing an array of 5 integers. And addresses in an array are expected to be consecutive... (in fact the C standard *mandates* they are.)

So we have the following equalities:

- `&(ptr[1]) == &(ptr[0]) + 1` per pointer arithmetics
- `(void *) &(ptr[1]) == ((void *) &(ptr[0])) + sizeof(int)` for byte addresses

Comment: Well, they are *guaranteed* to be consecutive.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Of course they are... Are you suggesting that I should rewrite that ? ;-)

Comment: `((void *) &(ptr[0])) + sizeof(int)`: Pointer arithmetic on `void*` is actually not standard C or C++.

Comment: I see that you did :-). It is one of the essential principles of the language, coming from C, because `a[i]`is equivalent to `*(i+a)` -- but I'm not telling you anything new.